# setfullscreenintent work only with tap on headup notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, onesignal

**My problem: setfullscreenintent() could not open the NotificationActivity and only shows  NotificationActivity when that opens by tapping  headup notification**

Note: I have to write all code in the class that extend **Application()** class (onesignal use **Application()** class to handle received notification)

After a day of searching and testing on several devices, I could not get any results.

Thank you for guiding me.

my code :

```
    val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java)
    val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, fullScreenIntent, 0)

    val notificationBuilder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText("test")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)

    val notificationManager = 
       this.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)as NotificationManager

    with(notificationManager) {
        val incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build()
        notify(0, incomingCallNotification)
    }
```

and i used this permission:

```
"android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"
```

and this :

```
 <activity android:name="ir.karpage.ui.NotificationActivity"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true">
```

Comment: How are you testing it? The activity should open automatically only if the system determines that the device is idle.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
I tested it when the app was open or closed or the phone was locked